# Invisible calendar in DatePicker

Tags: android

I've got strange problem - seems like android:calendarViewShown="false" makes calendar invisible, and its size is still counted in layout.

[image]

This is my xml for dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/from_text_view_label"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fromDatePicker"
        android:calendarViewShown="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/to_text_view_label"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toDatePicker"
        android:calendarViewShown="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm using simple AlertDialog with this layout. How can i fix size of dialog window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Евгений Кравцов: Just add this in your **DatePicker**

```
android:datePickerMode="spinner"
```

Please read this article

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#attr_android:datePickerMode